# Table inserting blank cells

Tags: html, powershell, parsing, formatting, hashtable

I'm trying to import a list into an HTML-formatted table. It seems to be working as expected except that I'm getting many cells populating with blanks. I've tried to remove all extra spaces using trim and other methods but the extra spaces still end up in the table.

Here is the code.

```
uemcli -d 192.168.1.100 -u Local/admin -p admin /event/alert/hist show -acknowledged no |
    select -Skip 4 > $PSSCriptRoot\output.txt

$nl = [System.Environment]::NewLine
$unity = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt

$unity = $unity -replace "[0-9]:",""
$unity = $unity -replace "=",":"
$unity = $unity -replace "$n1$n1",""
$unity = $unity.Trim()

$UnitySummary = ($unity) -split '$n1$n1' | foreach {
    $Stringdata = $_.Replace(':','=') -replace '$n1',''
    New-Object PSObject -Property $(ConvertFrom-StringData $Stringdata)
} 

$style = @"
<style>
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse; }
TH{border-width: 2px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid; border-color: black;background-color: #08088A; color: white; font-size: 67%;}
TD{border-width: 2px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid; border-color: black; font-size: 100%;}
</style>
"@

$unitySummary |
    select 'Id','Time','Message' |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $style |
    Out-File $PSScriptRoot\weboutput.html
```

Here is the raw file I'm processing in the first line (output.txt):

```
1:    ID           = alert_457
      Time         = 2017-12-16 02:46:04.937
      Message      = A recommended system software (version 4.2.1.9535982) is now available for download. 
      Description  = "A recommended system software is now available for download. To ensure optimal system performance, EMC recommends upgrading to this version. Run a health check about a week before installing the upgrade to identify and resolve any underlying issues that may prevent a successful update. (https://172.16.243.100/help/webhelp/en_US/index.html?#unity_t_update_software.html)"
      Severity     = info
      Acknowledged = no

2:    ID           = alert_456
      Time         = 2017-12-15 01:04:33.480
      Message      = Host 172.16.243.13 is operating normally.
      Description  = "The component is operating normally. No action is required."
      Severity     = info
      Acknowledged = no

3:    ID           = alert_455
      Time         = 2017-12-15 01:04:33.367
      Message      = Host 172.16.243.12 is operating normally.
      Description  = "The component is operating normally. No action is required."
      Severity     = info
      Acknowledged = no

4:    ID           = alert_454
      Time         = 2017-12-15 01:04:33.245
      Message      = Host 172.16.243.11 is operating normally.
      Description  = "The component is operating normally. No action is required."
      Severity     = info
      Acknowledged = no

5:    ID           = alert_453
      Time         = 2017-12-15 00:04:38.035
      Message      = Unable to refresh managed server 172.16.243.13 because of a connection issue.
      Description  = "Failed to connect to host. Please check your network connection. (https://172.16.243.100/help/webhelp/en_US/index.html?#unity_t_unable_to_refresh_managed_server_because_of_a_connection_issue.html)"
      Severity     = critical
      Acknowledged = no

6:    ID           = alert_452
      Time         = 2017-12-15 00:04:37.935
      Message      = Unable to refresh managed server 172.16.243.12 because of a connection issue.
      Description  = "Failed to connect to host. Please check your network connection. (https://172.16.243.100/help/webhelp/en_US/index.html?#unity_t_unable_to_refresh_managed_server_because_of_a_connection_issue.html)"
      Severity     = critical
      Acknowledged = no

7:    ID           = alert_451
      Time         = 2017-12-15 00:04:37.753
      Message      = Unable to refresh managed server 172.16.243.11 because of a connection issue.
      Description  = "Failed to connect to host. Please check your network connection. (https://172.16.243.100/help/webhelp/en_US/index.html?#unity_t_unable_to_refresh_managed_server_because_of_a_connection_issue.html)"
      Severity     = critical
      Acknowledged = no
```

This is the output I'm getting. You can see the items are placed in the correct columns but the extra blank cells are being inserted causing the data to show up in the wrong row.

[image]

Comment: I think you are confusing `$nl` with `$n1`

Comment: `Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt` -> `Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt | Out-String`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers got it right. So simple. Feel free to post the answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

`Get-Content` doesn't read the input file as a single string but an array of lines. Because of that `New-Object` only ever creates objects with a single property. Piping that result through `select 'Id','Time','Message'` then adds the other properties, only with empty values.

Pipe the output of `Get-Content` through `Out-String` to fix this:

```
$unity = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt | Out-String
```

On PowerShell v3 and newer you can alternatively call `Get-Content` with the parameter `-Raw` to get the same result:

```
$unity = Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\output.txt -Raw
```

Answer (score 2):

Please accept Ansgar's answer, as it resolve the root of your issue. I'm posting this as additional help towards you getting what you're after.

Rather than reading the whole thing in as one string, splitting it up, doing several replacements (including converting all equal signs to colons, and then all colons to equal signs), take the large string, split it on the entries (indicated by a digit followed by a colon at the beginning of a line), and pipe each entry through `ConvertFrom-StringData` and make objects from that. It will get you what I'm pretty sure is exactly what you want to be able to pass into your table (selecting the properties that you want of coarse).

You could even skip the whole saving to disk and reading it back by piping your original command to `Out-String`.

```
$Unity = uemcli -d 192.168.1.100 -u Local/admin -p admin /event/alert/hist show -acknowledged no |
    select -Skip 4 |
    Out-String
$Unity -split '(?m)^\d:' |
    Where{$_.Trim()} |
    ForEach{ [PSCustomObject](ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_) }
```

Then you just pipe that out to your `ConvertTo-Html` and you're all set.

```
$Unity = uemcli -d 192.168.1.100 -u Local/admin -p admin /event/alert/hist show -acknowledged no |
        select -Skip 4 |
        Out-String
$style = @"
<style>
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse; }
TH{border-width: 2px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid; border-color: black;background-color: #08088A; color: white; font-size: 67%;}
TD{border-width: 2px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid; border-color: black; font-size: 100%;}
</style>
"@
$Unity -split '(?m)^\d:' |
    Where{$_.Trim()} |
    ForEach{ [PSCustomObject](ConvertFrom-StringData -StringData $_) } |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $style -as Table -Property 'Id','Time','Message' |
    Set-Content $PSScriptRoot\weboutput.html
```